# MC on Ubuntu: Save cursor in editor when leaving it

Tags: ubuntu, text-editors, cursor, midnight-commander

I am using midnight commander (mc) on ubuntu and have figured out that after editing or viewing a file and leaving it the cursor position is not saved after opening it once again.

Does anybody know an option that has to be changed in order to save the position in the file?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want MC to save the cursor position in *every* file you might view or edit?

I think that's a little too much to ask. I'm not aware that MC *remembers* the files from one 'viewing' to the next.

On the other hand, if you define an external editor, there may be a possibility of remembering the context.

Comment: thanx for the answer! *Do you want MC to save the cursor position in every file you might view or edit?* that's exactly what I would like to have. *I think that's a little too much to ask.* MC has its internal editor, so if other editors support such feature (for example, far manager on windows) I don't see the reasons why mc doesn't have to.